# 404 Error When Accessing URL through AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery

Not sure why, everything seems formatted fine, but I get the HTTP 404 error when attempting to access a function in my controller. Here's the aspx:

```
function CheckIfPacked() {
  if ($("#OrderNumber").val() != "") {
    var url = "/Packing/PackageTracking/CheckIfPacked";
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      cache: false,
      data: "orderNumber=" + $("#OrderNumber").val() + "&actionyes=GetSalesOrder()",
      success: function (data) {
      var domElement = $(data);
      if (data != "") {
        $('#MessageDiv').append(domElement);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And here's the controller:

```
public Result CheckIfPacked(string orderNumber) {
   var mesEntity = new MESEntities();
   var packh = from packhead in mesEntity.Packing_Transaction_Headers
               where packhead.Order_No_ == orderNumber
               select packhead.Completed_by_Packer;
   if (packh.First() == 0)
   {
      return new Result { Success = true, Message = string.Format("You have not finished packing order {0}, are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?", orderNumber) };
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

I think I've just stared at this too long. Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that your url is wrong. Open up Firebug or Fiddler to see what url you are accessing. I'm assuming Packing is your current area and PackageTracking is your controller, so I wouldn't be surprised to see you request http://localhost:port/Packing/PackageTracking/Packing/PackageTracking/CheckIfPacked

Comment: The URL should be good: localhost:port/Packing/PackageTracking/CheckIfPacked

Comment: The URL was correct, the location of the code was not. Massive code base.

Answer (score 0):

your method should be static and you should use webmethod attribute for your function :

```
[WebMethod]
public static Result CheckIfPacked(string orderNumber) {
   var mesEntity = new MESEntities();
   var packh = from packhead in mesEntity.Packing_Transaction_Headers
               where packhead.Order_No_ == orderNumber
               select packhead.Completed_by_Packer;
   if (packh.First() == 0)
   {
      return new Result { Success = true, Message = string.Format("You have not finished packing order {0}, are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?", orderNumber) };
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```